# Unable to get all elements in List<Dom.XmlNode>

Tags: apex, xml, document, dom, xmlnode

I'm trying to iterate through a List<Dom.XmlNode) in order to get all elements, but I am only able to get the first two (header - body)

Here's my code:

```
String xml='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:app="http://xmlns.snamretegas.it/schema/D5/GestioneRichieste/app_0165.xsd">'+
        '<soapenv:Header/>'+
        '<soapenv:Body>'+
           '<app:Prestazione cod_flusso="0165" cod_servizio="PN1">'+
              '<IdentificativiRichiesta>'+
                 '<piva_utente>91112519492</piva_utente>'+
                 '<piva_distr>82112519492</piva_distr>'+
                 '<cod_prat_utente>1</cod_prat_utente>'+
                 '<cod_prat_distr>11</cod_prat_distr>'+
              '</IdentificativiRichiesta>'+
              '<GestioneAppuntamento>'+
                 '<gest_app>Y</gest_app>'+
              '</GestioneAppuntamento>'+
              '<Appuntamento>'+
                 '<codice_appuntamento>AP1</codice_appuntamento>'+
                 '<data_app>06/05/2021</data_app>'+
                 '<fascia_oraria>17:00/18:00</fascia_oraria>'+
                 '<stima_durata>1</stima_durata>'+
                 '<data_limite_modifica>06/05/2021</data_limite_modifica>'+
                 '<ora_limite_validita>16:00</ora_limite_validita>'+
              '</Appuntamento>'+
              '<Appuntamento>'+
                 '<codice_appuntamento>AP2</codice_appuntamento>'+
                 '<data_app>07/05/2021</data_app>'+
                 '<fascia_oraria>08:00/11:00</fascia_oraria>'+
                 '<stima_durata>3</stima_durata>'+
                 '<data_limite_modifica>06/05/2021</data_limite_modifica>'+
                 '<ora_limite_validita>18:00</ora_limite_validita>'+
              '</Appuntamento>'+
              '<Esito>'+
                 '<verifica_risp>1</verifica_risp>'+
                 '<cod_causale>15</cod_causale>'+
                 '<motivazione>234</motivazione>'+
              '</Esito>'+
              '<DatiAggiuntivi>'+
                 '<stato>DA ESEGUIRE</stato>'+
              '</DatiAggiuntivi>'+
           '</app:Prestazione>'+
        '</soapenv:Body>'+
     '</soapenv:Envelope>';

Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(xml);
Dom.XmlNode root = doc.getRootElement();
//system.debug(root);
//system.debug(root.getChildren());

List<dom.XmlNode> elements = root.getChildren();
for (Dom.XmlNode e : elements) {
    system.debug(e.getName());
}
```

Those two debugs return the following:

> 09:20:35:002 USER_DEBUG
> [45]|DEBUG|XMLNode[ELEMENT,Envelope,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/,null,[common.apex.api.dom.XmlNode$NamespaceDef@f7aa2a5,
> common.apex.api.dom.XmlNode$NamespaceDef@4beb847e],[XMLNode[ELEMENT,Header,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/,null,null,null,null,],
> XMLNode[ELEMENT,Body,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,Prestazione,http://xmlns.snamretegas.it/schema/D5/GestioneRichieste/app_0165.xsd,[common.apex.api.dom.XmlNode$Attribute@5a666118,
> common.apex.api.do

> 09:20:35:002 USER_DEBUG
> [46]|DEBUG|(XMLNode[ELEMENT,Header,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/,null,null,null,null,],
> XMLNode[ELEMENT,Body,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,Prestazione,http://xmlns.snamretegas.it/schema/D5/GestioneRichieste/app_0165.xsd,[common.apex.api.dom.XmlNode$Attribute@5a666118,
> common.apex.api.dom.XmlNode$Attribute@10a773d2],null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,IdentificativiRichiesta,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,piva_utente,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,

> 09:20:35:002 USER_DEBUG
> [50]|DEBUG|XMLNode[ELEMENT,Header,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/,null,null,null,null,]

> 09:20:35:002 USER_DEBUG
> [50]|DEBUG|XMLNode[ELEMENT,Body,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,Prestazione,http://xmlns.snamretegas.it/schema/D5/GestioneRichieste/app_0165.xsd,[common.apex.api.dom.XmlNode$Attribute@5a666118,
> common.apex.api.dom.XmlNode$Attribute@10a773d2],null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,IdentificativiRichiesta,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,piva_utente,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,91112519492,]],null,],
> XMLNode[ELEMENT,piva_distr,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,

system.debug(e.getName()) only returns Header and Body.

How can I access other elements? I need those 'IdentificativiRichiesta', 'Gestione Appuntamento' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike JSON (where Salesforce provides us a good tool to parse *and deserialize*), working with XML in Apex is a lot more manual.

The classes in the Dom namespace (Document and XmlNode) parse the XML, but getting the data into a useable form from there is our responsibility.

The reason why you're only getting `header` and `body` is because those are the only children of the root element of your XML. To go further and access `IdentificativiRichiesta` and `Gestione Appuntamento`, you'd need to additionally iterate over the children of `body`, and then iterate over the children of `app:Prestazione`

Nested data structures like this functionally require an equal number of nested for loops. Putting everything into one giant set of for loops makes it hard to develop, maintain, and understand (in my opinion). So instead of doing that, my preferred approach is to create small apex classes to mimic the structure of your XML (pretty much what the JSON2Apex tool hosted on Heroku does, but for JSON instead of XML).

Here's an example to get you started

```java
public class Envelope{
    Header head;
    Body b;

    public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
        // more looping
        for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
            switch on child.getName(){
                when 'Header'{
                }
                when 'Body'{
                    b = new Body();
                    b.deserialize(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Pretty much going to need one class per tag
public class Header{
    // and each class needs a deserialize method
    // This is where we'll handle pulling out any primitive values like
    //   strings, dates, integers, and the like
    // If you expect a node to be empty, then the deserialize() method can
    //   also be empty
    public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
    }
}

public class Body{
    // Child tags become class variables of their parent type
    Prestazione p;

    // If you have primitive values or xml attributes you want to capture for the
    //   Body tag, then they become variables of that class
    String cod_flusso;
    String cod_servizio;

    public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
        // There's going to be a lot of typecasting involved
        cod_flusso = (String)node.getAttributeValue('code_flusso');
        cod_servizio = (String)node.getAttributeValue('cod_servizio');

        // Now we start looping
        // This pattern is going to be repeated in subsequent classes
        for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
            if(child.getName() == 'Prestazione'){
                p = new Prestazione();

                // Now we pass on the processing to Prestazione
                // Doing things like this means that the complexity at any
                //   one level is manageable
                p.deserialize(child);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Prestazione{
    public IdentificativiRichiesta richiesta;
    public GestioneAppuntamento ga;

    // Multiple children of the same type naturally fit into a List collection
    public List<Appuntamento> appuntamentoList;

    // You can still have a constructor to take care of basic setup
    public Prestazione(){
        appuntamentoList = new List<Appuntamento>();
    }

    public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
        // more looping
        for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
            switch on child.getName(){
                when 'IdentificativiRichiesta'){
                    richiesta = new IdentificativiRichiesta();
                    richiesta.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'GestioneAppuntamento'{
                    ga = new GestioneAppuntamento();
                    ga.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Appuntamento'{
                    Appuntamento a = new Appuntamento();
                    a.deserialize(child);

                    // don't forget to add the instance to your list
                    appuntamentoList.add(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class IdentificativiRichiesta{
    // When we get to items that only contain primitive values, it's time
    //  to just extract them directly
    String piva_utente;
    String piva_distr;
    Integer cod_prat_utente;
    Integer cod_prat_distr;

    public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
        for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
            switch on child.getName(){
                when 'piva_utente'{
                    piva_utente = (String)child.getValue();
                }
                when 'piva_distr'{
                    piva_distr = (String)child.getValue();
                }
                when 'cod_prat_utente'{
                    cod_prat_utente = (Integer)child.getValue();
                }
                when 'cod_prat_distr'{
                    cod_prat_distr = (Integer)child.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// and so on
```

```java
// In the end, you'd use this by passing in the root node to the envelope instance
Envelope e = new Envelope();
e.deserialize(xmlDoc.getRootElement());

// Afterwords, you have access via dot notation
system.debug(e.b.p.richiesta);
```

That code example isn't tested, and not as polished as it could be (variable naming in particular is a pain point). I imagine that handling xml namespaces is going to take some extra consideration as well (but that should be simple enough if you look through the XmlNode documentation).

The main points are:

- With XML, we have to do a lot of processing ourselves
- I think the best way to do that is to mimic the structure with classes
- The processing done in each class is minimal (and similar in each class), and we rely on the structure of the classes to traverse the XML (depth-first)

Writing a test for this is going to be at least as painful as writing the deserialization (as you'll need to generate some appropriate XML in your test to feed into the code being tested)